# Как запустить приложение от имени администратора, runas (bat-ник) не подходит. C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, права-доступа

Помогите разобраться с проблемой. Работая под админом приложение запускает второе (вспомогательное) и выполняет все действия без проблем, как только переношу этот комплект на другой комп (под гостем) все идет наперекосяк, уверен что если запустить с правами администратора будет работать как надо, пробовал через планировщик запускать (для гостя).
 UAC окошко мне надо избежать, чтобы пользователь не вводил пароль каждый раз, тем более этот пароль ему не допустимо знать.
запускаю вспомогательное приложение таким образом:

```
  int ProcessStartOk333(string path, string name, Boolean start)
            {
                string processName = name;
                var processExists = Process.GetProcesses().Any(p => p.ProcessName == processName);
                var process = Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProcessName == processName);
                if (!processExists && start == true)
                {
                    string processPath = path;
                    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(processPath)
                    { Verb = "runas" };
                    startInfo.Password = ReadPassword(textBox2.Text); //попытка ввести пароль администратора таким образом 
                    startInfo.UserName = textBox3.Text;
                    Process.Start(startInfo); //есть запуск
                                              //  MessageBox.Show("запустили");
                }
            }

 public static SecureString ReadPassword(string password)
        {
            SecureString secPass = new SecureString();
            for (int i = 0; i < password.Length; i++)
                secPass.AppendChar(password[i]);
            return secPass;
        }
```

Приложения обновляют друг друга через фтп, т.е. закрывается сперва одно, обновляется, потом другое аналогично, метод колхозный другого не знаю собрал на коленке как мог. Суть в том что под гостем толи прав не хватает толи еще какая гадость в мат части (которую я крайне медлено осваиваю, дислексия прогрессирует похоже)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050478/how-do-i-create-edit-a-manifest-file

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/71f68da8-c565-47a7-9df4-78b282610b2e/-?forum=programminglanguageru

Comment: к сожалению параметр в манифесте - requireAdministrator наоборот требует ввести пароль админа, UAC окошко мне надо избежать, чтобы пользователь не вводил пароль каждый раз.. сейчас поправлю текст первоначальный моего вопроса

Answer (score -1):

Добавляем манифест файл в проект и прописываем в нем

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: Попробуй запустить с level="highestAvailable".
Либо исключить все функции, которые требуют админправ, ибо то что вы хотите это уже обход UAC

Comment: спасибо, буду делать через планировщик.

Comment: удалось добится что через проводник Win 7  не требуется пароль на запуск вспомогательного приложения, но запуск из первичного приложения когда происходит пароль он все же просит, как же так?

Comment: Когда вы запускаете вспомогательное приложение вы наследуете права приложения, которое его запускало.
То есть если вы запустили 1.exe с правами администратора, то все приложения, которые запустятся через него будут иметь права администратора